# Access IStatePropertyAccessor botstate in a controller in v4

Tags: botframework

If you need to access the state in botframework v4 outside of a bot context (that does not implement `IBot`), for instance a Controller, how could you easily get a hold of this state object? The problem is that you can't really inject it directly because it needs to be initialized with a ChannelId and ConversationId.

The following approach works but looks a bit strange as I am using the `TestAdapter` to initialize the `TurnContext`. Isn't there a better, more obvious method to get a hold of the state?

```
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyBotAccessors _botAccessors;

    public SampleController(MyBotAccessors botAccessors)
    {
            _botAccessors = botAccessors;
    }
}

public async Task Reset(string conversationKey, string channelId)
{
    var turnContext = new TurnContext(new TestAdapter(), new Activity { ChannelId = channelId, Conversation = new ConversationAccount { Id = conversationKey } });
    await _botAccessors.MyContextState.SetAsync(turnContext, new MyContextState().Reset());
    await _botAccessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need state without the conversation?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes the trigger is external, so outside of the conversation because it's not the actual user who triggers it, it could be an operator that resets the conversation for a user after a manual intervention